# Is it possible to match a pattern using a regular expression across a newline in UltraEdit?

Tags: regex, text-editor, ultraedit

The UltraEdit text editor includes a Perl and Unix compatible regular expression engine for searching.

I want to be able to match a string line this:

```
<branch id="attribute">
    <leaf id="attribute"/>
    <leaf id="attribute"/>
    <leaf id="attribute"/>
</branch>
```

With something like this:

```
/<branch id="attribute">.*</branch>/gis
```

Is there a way to accomplish this using UltraEdit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Perl regular expressions selected, you can do something like:

```
<branch id="attribute">[\s\S]*</branch>
```

where \s is any whitespace character, including newline and return and \S is any other character. Note that this is greedy by default, so if you have the following string:

```
<branch id="attribute">
  <leaf id="attribute"/>
  <leaf id="attribute"/>
  <leaf id="attribute"/>
</branch>
<branch id="attribute">
  <leaf id="attribute"/>
  <leaf id="attribute"/>
  <leaf id="attribute"/>
</branch>
```

then the one regular expression will find the ENTIRE string as one match.  If you don't want to do this, then add `?` as follows:

```
<branch id="attribute">[\s\S]*?</branch>
```

As you can see from the answers, there are many ways to accomplish this in UltraEdit!

NOTE: Tested with UltraEdit 14.20.

Comment: I don't know if UltraEdit supports the /s modifier like the OP used, but the [\s\S] trick should work just as well. That, plus the '?' for non-greedy matching, should answer the question in full.

Comment: Thanks.  This works for me.  The bit about the greedy matching is useful as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you put (?s) at the start of pattern it'll enable single line mode so \r\n will not be excluded from matching .*

E.g., the following matches the whole of the branch element (in UEStudio 6 with Perl style regular expression):

```
(?s)<branch id="attribute">.*</branch>
```

Doing a little experiment some other Perl options are supported too. e.g. (?sx-i) at the start would be Single line, ignore eXtra whitespace in pattern, case sensitive (it seems to default to case insensitive).

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried:

```
/<branch id="attribute">[.\n]*</branch>/gis
```

Comment: He's asking about the regex syntax in a specific text editor, which doesn't use the syntax you are showing.  Also, \n may or may not match \r\n that is used on Windows, so you need to use [.\r\n] not just [.\n]